# C code runs faster when allocate and run inside main, slower when allocate elsewhere

Tags: c, performance

I was playing with CPU caches in C and i ran into a strange thing.

To play with CPU cache, I allocate a 2dim array of X lines and (cpu L1 cache size) columns.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LINES 1000
#define COLUMNS 64 * 1024 // L1 cache size on i3-3110M

void cache_hit(uint8_t **t) {
    uint64_t i = 0, j = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < LINES; ++j) {
        for(i = 0; i < COLUMNS; ++i) {
            t[j][i] = 255;
        }
    }
}

void cache_miss(uint8_t **t) {
    uint64_t i = 0, j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < COLUMNS; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < LINES; ++j) {
            t[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

// parce que je kiff le C...
void init_array(uint8_t ***t) {
    uint64_t j = 0;

    *t = calloc(LINES, sizeof(uint8_t *));
    for(j = 0; j < LINES; ++j) {
        (*t)[j] = calloc(COLUMNS, sizeof(uint8_t));
    }
}

#ifdef FROM_MAIN
int main(void) {
#else
void bench(void) {
#endif
    uint8_t **t = NULL;
    uint64_t j = 0;
    clock_t t_begin;
    clock_t t_end;
    clock_t t1, t2;

    puts("init...");
#ifdef ALLOC_IN_PLACE
    t = calloc(LINES, sizeof(uint8_t *));
    for(j = 0; j < LINES; ++j) {
        t[j] = calloc(COLUMNS, sizeof(uint8_t));
    }
#else
    init_array(&t);
#endif
    puts("bench...");

    /* cache hit */
    t_begin = clock();
    cache_hit(t);
    t_end = clock();

    t1 = t_end - t_begin;
    printf("cache hit time:  %ld\n", t1);
    /* */

    /* cache miss */
    t_begin = clock();
    cache_miss(t);
    t_end = clock();

    t2 = t_end - t_begin;
    printf("cache miss time: %ld\n", t2);
    /* */

    printf("run time factor: %f\n", ((double)t2)/((double)t1));

    for(j = 0; j < LINES; ++j) {
        free(t[j]);
    }
    free(t);
#ifndef FROM_MAIN
}
#endif

#ifndef FROM_MAIN
int main(void) {
    bench();
#endif

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I build with `gcc -O0 -Wall main.c -DFROM_MAIN -DALLOC_IN_PLACE` to allocate and run from main(), and `-DFROM_MAIN` to only run from main and allocate in a separate function (init_array).

The code runs six times slower when running from main and if the array was allocated from outside main().

**Update**: with -O0, no difference. With -O2 or -O3, clear difference happen.

I hope I have been clear.

Comment: Why are you even benchmarking at `-O0`?

Comment: maybe to have a benchmark not depending on the compiler's optimisations

Comment: running without compiler optimizations somewhat ensures the running code is really close to the C code you wrote.

Comment: There is a contradiction in your requirements. C doesn't have the notion of *cache* or *time*. Optimizer does. So asking *why* about these terms without using optimizer and keeping the code "really close to C" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I just updated the post because i didin't see that the problem happened only when using optimizations O2 and O3 only.

Comment: When allocated inline, the GCC seems to realize that `cache_hit` is just a loop of `memcpy`s. That explains the speed difference.